# How to tell if the sequence can "sum and/or sub" to $x$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, summation, problem-solving

Consider a sequence of length $n$ which elements are integers that were randomly (and uniformly) sampled from $[1,2,3...,x-2,x-1]$. One can wonder whether by addition and subtraction only, is it possible for the sequence to sum up to $x$?

For example let's consider the following sequence where $n=3$ and $x=10$

$[2,7,5]$

This sequence can "sum and/or sub" to $x=10$, as $7-2+5=10$ Please note that the first number can also be used to the negative so that the order of the sequence does not matter. The following sequence of length $n=4$ however cannot "sum and sub" to $x=10$

$[2,7,5,2]$

**Given $x$ and $n$, what is the probability that the sequence can "sum and/or sub" to $x$?**

Let's denote this probability $P(x,n)$. For $n=0$, $n=1$ and $n=2$, it is relatively easy. $P(x,0)=P(x,1)=0$ and $P(x,2)=\frac{1}{x-1}$ but it gets harder with larger values of $n$.

Comment: Side note: "sum and/or sub" is probably more suitable.

Comment: The worst-case complexity is $O(n!\cdot2^{n-1})$.

Comment: I would have thought that the worst case complexity is $2^{n}-1$. The order does not matter and the case where the largest number is subtracted by all the others cannot reach $x$ (as all numbers are lower than $x$).

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion. I edited the post.

Comment: I doubt that there's a general formula for the probability as a function of $x$ and $n$. I mean, of course there is, because any computer program can be converted into a formula, and a a computer program is feasible in this case, but I'm pretty sure that it's gonna look pretty nasty (lots of $\sum$ and $\prod$).

Comment: Yes, sorry about the complexity issue, you're right - we can simply choose a negative or positive sign next to each one of the elements in the sequence. So a worst-case complexity is $O(2^n)$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $2^{n}$ possible ways to make a sequence. With repitition, there are infinite number of sequences that work and an infinite number of sequences that don't. [Partitions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) would probably help you out, as they can get you how many ways you can add up to a specific number. For subtraction, you will have to improvise, usually by finding how much you are over and then using a partition for that result, and inverting its sign.

Either way, this isn't going to be easy.